# Regarding Users in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have installed an Oracle 12c database on my system. I had an application which need to access the database.

Previously in Oracle 11g, I used the following commands to create an user.

```
create user name identified by name;  
grant connect,create session,resource,create view to name;
```

Can anyone tell me how to create a user in Oracle 12c with my above requirements?
I used the following statements but my installation is showing a fatal error saying

```
FATAL ERROR - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
```

Following were the statements used.

```
create user c##test1 identified by test1 container = ALL;
grant connect,create session,resource,create view to test1;
```

Comment: 1) Have you created and configured pluggable database? 2) Second `create user` statement creates common user account ( it seems like you want to create a local one) and it means, you are not connected to a pluggable database. In order to create a local user account, you need to connect to a pluggable database(if it has been created and access to it has been appropriately configured).

Comment: I have created a pluggable database...and how did you confirm that I want to create a local user account rather than common. Till now I am unable to understand to create a local/common

Comment: `c##` prefix is used only for common user accounts in 12c. You wont be able to create a local user with that prefix. So if your statement executed successfully it means that you connected to container database (CDB) and created a common user account. Now, in order to create a local user account you need to connect to a PDB (`sys/pass@PDB_TNS_NAME as sysdba` for instance) and then attempt to create a user, local to that PDB, user.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you need to use a common user account to be able to connect to any pluggable database and do something useful , then after you've created a common user, you have to log in(`as sysdba` for instance) to each PDB, that common user needs access to,  and grant appropriate roles and privileges to that common user.

Comment: If you grant the (deprecated) `resource` role there is no need to also grant `connect` and `create session` or `create view` - those are already included.

Comment: Agreeing with horsey ... but you should not use RESOURCE. Be specific in your grants.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Only `connect` role and `create session` system privilege are mutually exclusive - if you grant `connect` role, then there is no need to explicitly  grant `create session` system privilege. `resource` role doesn't cover those privileges, and does not include `create view` privilege either. But it definitely contains more privileges that a user might need.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov: you are right. I should have worded that differently. The combination of roles as shown kind of indicates that it was copied from somewhere without understanding what the individual roles actually do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best Practice is to create a tablespace and assign that to the User.

Just to make it easier to understand use same name for username and tablespace

`CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE C##1

DATAFILE '/path/to/datafile/C##1.dbf'

SIZE 10M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 5M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED

EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL 
SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO 
NOLOGGING;`

---

### --Create User

`CREATE USER  C##1

IDENTIFIED BY password 
DEFAULT  TABLESPACE C##1

QUOTA UNLIMITED ON C##1;`

Comment: Is the above error mentioned has something to do with tablespace?

Comment: I guess so. If you don't specify a tablespace while you create a tablespace, it takes a default tablespace called USER. By the looks of it error output, it looks like that. The tablespace could have exceeded its memory limit. I'm not sure.

Comment: The user/schema from which the new user is being created doesn't have any previllage on the "USER" tablespace. ALTER USER <username> QUOTA 100M ON <tablespace name> 
 
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO <username>. These grant might do the jov

Answer (score 1):

You should also give the user a quota on his default tablespace:

```
CREATE USER name
IDENTIFIED BY name
DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
QUOTA 50M /* or any other number that makes sense */ ON users

GRANT CONNECT, CREATE SESSION, RESOURCE, CREATE VIEW TO name;
```

Comment: A quota clause? yeah. Although you could specify `QUOTA UNLIMITED` if you don't want to start managing quotas.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
USERVALID=false;

if [ -z $1 ]; then
 echo -e "\nThis script will create a new common user in Oracle"
fi

while [[ $USERVALID == false ]]; do
 if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo -e "Username must start with 'c##' or 'C##'\n"
  read -p "Enter a username: " NEWUSER
 else
  NEWUSER=$1
 fi
 if [[ $NEWUSER == c##* ]]
 then
  USERVALID=true;
 elif [[ $NEWUSER == C##* ]]
 then
  USERVALID=true;
 else
  USERVALID=false;
  echo -e "\nInvalid username";
  if [ ! -z $1 ]; then
   echo -e "Username must start with 'c##' or 'C##'\n"
   exit 0
  fi
 fi
done

while [[ -z $NEWPWD ]]; do
 if [ -z $2 ]; then
  read -p "Enter a password: " NEWPWD
 else
  NEWPWD=$2
 fi
 if [[ -z $NEWPWD ]]
 then
  echo -e "Password must not be NULL"
 fi
done

get_user_status () {
 sqlplus -s / as sysdba <<!
 set heading off
 set feedback off
 set pages 0
 select username from all_users where username = '${NEWUSER^^}';
!
}

USERDROP=$(get_user_status)
if [[ $USERDROP =~ ${NEWUSER^^} ]]; then
 echo -e "\nUser already exists...\nAttempting to drop user\n"
 echo -e "DROP USER $NEWUSER CASCADE;" | sqlplus -s / as sysdba
 USERDROP=$(get_user_status)
 if [[ $USERDROP =~ ${NEWUSER^^} ]]; then
  echo -e "Please ensure user is disconnected from the database before proceeding.\n"
  exit 0
 fi
fi

echo -e "CREATE USER $NEWUSER IDENTIFIED BY $NEWPWD;"  | sqlplus -s / as sysdba

USERDROP=$(get_user_status)
if [[ ! $USERDROP =~ ${NEWUSER^^} ]]; then
 echo -e "You are a bad person.\n"
 exit 0
fi

echo -e "GRANT CREATE SESSION TO $NEWUSER;"            | sqlplus -s / as sysdba
echo -e "GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO $NEWUSER;"          | sqlplus -s / as sysdba
echo -e "GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO $NEWUSER;"           | sqlplus -s / as sysdba
echo -e "GRANT CREATE DATABASE LINK TO $NEWUSER;"      | sqlplus -s / as sysdba
echo -e "GRANT CREATE TABLE TO $NEWUSER;"              | sqlplus -s / as sysdba
echo -e "GRANT CREATE VIEW TO $NEWUSER;"               | sqlplus -s / as sysdba
echo -e "GRANT CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TO $NEWUSER;"  | sqlplus -s / as sysdba
echo -e "GRANT QUERY REWRITE TO $NEWUSER;"             | sqlplus -s / as sysdba
echo -e "GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO $NEWUSER;"          | sqlplus -s / as sysdba
echo -e "GRANT SELECT ON SYS.V_\$SESSION TO $NEWUSER;" | sqlplus -s / as sysdba
echo -e "GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_LOCK TO $NEWUSER;"  | sqlplus -s / as sysdba
echo -e "GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO $NEWUSER;"      | sqlplus -s / as sysdba

echo -e "\nAll done!\n"
```

Comment: Note: Script will drop an existing user without prompting.